# Xbox One included chat headset not working

Tags: xbox-one

So I got an Xbox one for Christmas this year. I mainly got it to play halo with my friends. I knew beforehand that the console came with a chat headset. Upon opening, the headset would not work. There is no indication that it has been plugged in. Nothing in the devices menu either. It is the headset with the large plug with all the buttons. My xbox One console is a 500 gb Halo: The Master Chief Collection Bundle. It is also black if that is important.
Please reply if you have any answers to my problem.

Comment: Have you tried taking it back to the shop which sold you and see if you can get a replacement / repaired under warranty?

Comment: Well I am 800 miles from home. And it's from Amazon so I'm really just looking for a fix more than a refund. If you know any way then please tell. Thanks for the last case scenario though.

Comment: Those defaults suck so bad. You sometimes have to unplug it and replug it a few times. Check the mute button. If the controller is connecting it, the mute button will light up when you press it. Sometimes the game can register your controller, and let you play,but it will still not associate the controller as being you. Ie, controller will work as intended, but it wont actually link your headset. If all else fails, see if you can stream to a windows 10 lappy. If you have the laptop with you, you might gwt away with still using the tv,but directing voice through the laptop mic

Comment: Definitely try updating your controller through the xbox settings. This has a big impact on mic functionality.

Comment: What have you tried to solve your problem? Have you updated the controller and headset? Have you run a test as by https://support.xbox.com/en-GB/xbox-one/accessories/wired-headset-help or tested it in party with someone? What does the party say when you connect with your headset?

Comment: The part says that I have no headset. I don't have a controller usb so I can't update.

Answer (score 1):

The best bet is to update the controller via a USB connection.  However, I have experienced multiple controllers that have had a broken port for the connection to the headset.  Unfortunately, there is a small solder point inside the controller that seems to break sometimes from the torque of inserting the headset adapter into the controller port because of the bump meant to secure the headset adapter.

The only fix for this is to disassemble the controller and try to repair the solder (this nullifies the warranty) or to return/replace the controller.

Comment: It's worth adding that the new version of this controller accepts 3.5mm for the headset, a standardised connection. The controllers are often replaced, under warranty, and most stores will likely only have the new version to replace it with.

Answer (score -1):

I know from past experience that the Xbox headsets do not work. Consider getting Turtlebeach or Beetlejuice for those work really well